# how to edit part of footer

Tags: footer

My site: up8.431.myftpupload.com

A graphic designer hired me and I inherited this site from a previous developer. I need to change the part of the footer where it has the phone number, email, and address. Problem is, I can't figure out where and how the previous developer added that functionality and how i can edit it.

Tried:

1. Customizer -> widgets - Your theme has 7 widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them.You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages....so no go
2. Customizer -> footer widgets - They're enabloed but not sure how that helps me. I don't see how i can edit them and disabling them does nothing. So I'm thinking this footer section might not be a widget.
3. Customizer -> footer bottom - This is disabled. so that doesn't help. Enabling them just gives me the copyright editable content.
4. Appearance ->widgets - I'm not totally familiar with this section but it still looks to have the default footer1-4 sidebar, etc widgets. nothing different.

I'm pretty sure this a "lack of experience" thing and I appreciate your help in advance. I'm totally baffled
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in your page says that the content is generated via elementor. I never used it, but probably you can find Elementor Bookmark in you admin panel or in Customizer->Elementor.

In other cases if user is using child-theme code may be in `functions.php` or added via plugin like `Contact Form 7`.

Comment: This was it. I didn't realize there was an Elementor tab in the dashboard menu. I went there and found that the section of the footer that I needed changed was actually created with Elementor like you said and easily editable. Thx agin!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in a footer widget, then there are a few places it could be:

- functions.php of the theme (in /wp-content/themes/oceanwp/)
- functions.php of the child theme
- one of the page templates of the theme or child theme

You could do a find in files or grep with your favorite tool to search for the current address to find it.

Some themes also have a settings page under the Appearance menu.